# Add YYMMDD as prefix and Initial as suffix automatically

Tags: windows, automation, shared, savefiledialog, multi-user

I'm managing files in our shared folder.

At some point in time in the past, it contained more than 500 thousand and 1 billion files!

I have created some regulations to naming conventions, but it still doesn't seem to work well for 20 users accessing the shared folder.

Is there any way to automatically modify filenames every time users save their office documents (.PPT, .DOC, .XLS, .TXT, .JPG, ETC., ETC.)?

For example, I was thinking I could add YYMMDD as a prefix and the user's initials as a "suffix."  If you are confused by what I mean by "suffix" then maybe I can clarify.

Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: What is your purpose? Are you trying to maintain history of the user who modified the document? As and when a new user will change, the file name also will change making old links invalid. This case looks like should be handled by a document server such as SharePoint.

Comment: My purpose is adding prefix YYMMDD and initial  automatically when user save file. Yes.. I need to add date prefix and initial to suffix name automatically, user only write file name and once it saved, date and initial automatically added in saved file.

Comment: Dear Experts, Or... Is there any software (preferable freeware) which can handle my purpose?